# XlsxWriter: use color scale based on a function of the values in the cells

Tags: python, excel, xlsxwriter, colormap

## Question (XlsxWriter)

Hello,
I'm using `XlsxWriter`, and I'd like to know if there's a way to use the `conditional_format` using a color scale, but not based directly on the values contained in the cells, but on a function applied to those.

---

##### Practical example

This code does somewhat what I need, but it uses the value contained in each cell to derive the cell's color.

I want it to do the same thing, but, in order to determine the cell's color, it should use the result of a function applied to the cell's value (instead of the cell's value directly).

```py
import xlsxwriter

# Create a new Excel workbook and add a worksheet
workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook('suffix_with_color.xlsx')
worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet()

# Sample data for the worksheet
data = [
    [10, 20, 30],
    [40, 50, 60],
    [70, 80, 90]
]

# Write the data and conditional format cell-by-cell to the worksheet
for row_index, row_data in enumerate(data):
    for col_index, cell_value in enumerate(row_data):
        worksheet.write(row_index, col_index, cell_value)

# Define the custom color scale using RGB values (Red, Yellow, Green)
color_scale = {
    'type': '3_color_scale',
    'min_color': '#FF5733',  # Red
    'mid_color': '#FFE600',  # Yellow
    'max_color': '#33FF57'   # Green
}

# Apply the custom color scale to the range of cells (in this example, all cells)
worksheet.conditional_format('A1:C3', color_scale)

# Close the workbook to save the file
workbook.close()
```

---

I'm also open to use other libraries, if that's the case.

Thanks in advance for the help!

I tried to call `conditional_format` after writing each cell, pass the color map to it, as well as the value I wanted to consider for coloring (instead of the plain cell's value), but all the cells had the same color.

Comment: Do you mean the the cell rather than having a value `10` you want it to have a formula like `=SUM(F1:F5)` where that formula is equal to `10`?

Comment: @moken not really, I mean a function of solely the value contained in that cell, not involving other cells.
In particular, I don't really have numbers in my cells, but strings representing numbers with a certain confidence interval, something like "24 +- 0.8". I want to color the cell only based on the "24".

Answer (score 0):

I don't think the three color graded scale can work with functions within the cell, but there are other options that could be used.
This not necessarily be the best method, I'm not an expert on applying CF solutions, however you can build your own scaling through setting up different colour values to suit formulas extracting data from your sheet.

So going on the example you provided;

1. A formula is used to obtain the numeric component of cell
   *"24 +- 0.8". I want to color the cell only based on the "24"*
   A simple `LEFT` text `split` is used to obtain `24` from the value `"24 +- 0.8"`
2. Formulas are added to CF that applies a colour based on the value 24

```py
import xlsxwriter

# Create a new Excel workbook and add a worksheet
workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook('suffix_with_color.xlsx')
worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet()

# Sample data for the worksheet
data = [
    ['10 +- 0.8', '20 +- 0.8', '30 +- 0.8'],
    ['40 +- 0.8', '50 +- 0.8', '60 +- 0.8'],
    ['70 +- 0.8', '80 +- 0.8', '90 +- 0.8']
]

# Write the data and conditional format cell-by-cell to the worksheet
for row_index, row_data in enumerate(data):
    for col_index, cell_value in enumerate(row_data):
        worksheet.write(row_index, col_index, cell_value)

### Dictionary of cell value to colour coding
value_to_colour_dict = {
    10: 'FF7F25',
    20: 'FFA816',
    30: 'FFE608',
    40: 'E1E609',
    50: 'BCEE1C',
    60: '8EF330',
    70: '61F943',
    80: '33FF57'
}

### First condition, value <10  is slightly different formula to the rest
worksheet.conditional_format('$A$1:$C$3', {
    'type': 'formula',
    'criteria': '=IF(INT(LEFT(A1,2))<=10,TRUE,FALSE)',
    "format": workbook.add_format({'bg_color': 'FF5733'})
})

### Other formulas follows the same pattern, value between two numbers
for range_value, colour_format in value_to_colour_dict.items():
    formula = f'=IF(AND(INT(LEFT(A1,2))>{range_value},INT(LEFT(A1,2))<={range_value + 10}),TRUE,FALSE)'

    ### Add the CF to the sheet
    worksheet.conditional_format('$A$1:$C$3', {
        'type': 'formula',
        'criteria': formula,
        "format": workbook.add_format({'bg_color': colour_format})
    })

# Close the workbook to save the file
workbook.close()
```

Example output screenshot

[image: Example Screen shot]